# Problems migrating Joomla website

Tags: php, joomla

Im planning to update an joomla template for an customer, i made an subfolder at my own host so i can test it so her site isnt shutdown the time im busy working on it.

When i copied all the files and (i think) fixed the database on my own server (also tried to fix the config.php file) i tried to go to the template but get realy alot of errors

http://jurjenfolkertsma.nl/willy/ here they are listed

i realy dont understand what gone wrong, (maybe its an diffrend version of php then the main hosting server?)

Does anyone ever had this problem or know any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to **php.ini** on your server (which you probably won't), open the file, search for this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and replace it with this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

As mentioned before, you most likely won't have access to the **php.ini** file on the server, in which case, you can add the following to the top of the index.php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE);
```

You are getting these error due to being on PHP 5.4

Comment: You still haven't properly connected to the database as I still see the error `Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL`. Sort this out first ;)

Comment: Im now running it on localhost xamp server, only problem left is now the admin login on localhost haha